# Consume JAX-WS Web Services

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws

I dont have WSDL just having Sample request and response,Is it possible to consume JAX-WS Web service without having WSDL in J2EE environment?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, [SAAJ](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhg.html) could be a possible solution, it's a low level API that would let you to construct and send SOAP messages to any endpoint.

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
QName bodyName = new QName("http://example.org/", "HelloWorld", "hello");
SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);

SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = factory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, "http://example.org/soap");
```